# Writing a script to convert images to text with references and footnotes?

Tags: ocr

I have a stack of hundreds of sheets of paper that makes up a book. The physical copy includes the text of the book, references in the text, and footnotes (with their respective reference numbers) at the bottom of almost every page. However, I only have one document with the book's text, and a separate document with every footnote, separated by linebreaks. There is no document containing the text with references and the footnotes.

I need to put the footnotes in their proper places in the text document by referring to their positions on the physical copy. Is there a way to automate this? I was thinking of scanning every page and using an OCR tool to convert the scanned images to text, but I'm wondering whether the software would pick up on the references.

If this isn't possible, has anyone found a solution to this sort of problem? I want to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: We aren't here to make code for you. Post what you have tried so far and we can help. We aren't here to do your work for you. Also your title isn't really a question.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me. I'm wondering whether this is possible, and if so, how I might proceed. If someone has written a script that can do exactly this, that would be very handy, but as long as software up to this task exists, writing a script to do this should be trivial.

Comment: It's still asking for code and SO doing the work for you. List what you have tried so far.